# Is there anyway to find out if a route has a (cheaper) code share partner?

Tags: air-travel, bookings, code-share

While looking around for flights from Sydney to Sri Lanka (SYD-CMB) I narrowed down the possible connections through south east Asia. The best connection was via Singapore. By pure chance I found it is cheaper to buy a code share Virgin flight than an actual Singapore Airlines ticket.  This seems like a useful trick.

Is there any way to find all the code share partners for a particular route?

Comment: Good question. Last week I booked a Czech Airlines flight to Korea which was much cheaper than the corresponding Korean air flight (identical connection) - although I couldn't find any information on Google verifying they are the same.

Comment: When reading the question, I wondered about its motivation. Did anybody ever see that a modern flight search engine only shows the more expensive flight but misses the cheaper code share flight?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[FlightStats](http://www.flightstats.com/) gives code-share information for any flight.

Looking up a flight number on that site gives a listing of its codesahres, among other flight information.  For example, if you enter [AC (Air Canada) 8975 on Dec-04-2015](http://www.flightstats.com/go/FlightStatus/flightStatusByFlight.do?airline=%28AC%29+Air+Canada&flightNumber=8975&departureDate=2015-12-04&x=8&y=12) into the Flight Status box, click Search, and then scroll down to the "AC 8975 Flight Information" box, you see an entry saying:

```
Codeshares:     This flight marketed as a codeshare flight by the following airlines:
(LX) SWISS 4688
(LH) Lufthansa 6692
(CA) Air China 7459
```

Unfortunately, the site only allows flights to be searched up to a few days ahead.  Thus you won't be able to look for flights on the day you want to travel (unless you're planning a last-minute trip).  But looking for the same flight number within a range of days (yesterday, today, tomorrow, etc., preferably including the day of the week on which you want to travel) should give a sense of which airlines are likely to code-share the flight.  Of course, this won't help if the flight you're looking for is a new service that hasn't yet begun, or if a particular airline pair is set to begin a code-share arrangement in the future.

Notice that even if the same flight runs every day of the week, it does not necessarily have the same code-share partners every day.  For example, looking up [the above flight one day earlier (Dec-03-2015)](http://www.flightstats.com/go/FlightStatus/flightStatusByFlight.do?airline=%28AC%29+Air+Canada&flightNumber=8975&departureDate=2015-12-03&x=8&y=12), we see that it lists only LH, not LX or CA.  (I imagine that a marketing airline might choose to share another carrier's flight only if they have a flight of their own connecting to it on that particular day.)

As a slight alternative, you can choose "By Route" in the Flight Status search box and then enter departure and arrival airports to get a list of flights operating that route, including code-shares.  Again, it doesn't let you view flights more than ~3 days ahead, but you can see what airlines run that route by checking a few days around the current date.

Answer (score 3):

While I'm not aware of any site that just lists codesharing partners for everyone, most airlines list their codeshare partners on their website.

For the example, you give, Singapore Airlines shows the [list of partners on their site](http://www.singaporeair.com/en_UK/about-us/psh-codeshare-psh/).  However, this is for all routes and you'd still need to work out which of those are on the route you're after.

Comment: http://www.singaporeair.com/en_UK/about-us/psh-codeshare-psh/psh-codeshare-dest/ is a better page

Answer (score 1):

Subscription sites such as [ExpertFlyer](http://expertflyer.com) will show you all flights, including codeshares for the same flight, so you could, e.g., search for flights SYD-CMB leaving at a certain time, and see them all.  The site will also show you all published fares SYD-CMB so you can see which is cheaper.  Free sites such as [Google flights](https://www.google.com/flights/) and [Matrix](http://matrix.itasoftware.com) will show you both flights and prices, so will be more convenient, and more to the point of what you want to know.